# PDO Statement does not return full array

Tags: php, arrays, pdo

I cant figure out why i only get 1 entry in the returning array, when the table has 4 entries in total.

My PDO code is:

```
$stmtkat = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM kategorie");
$stmtkat->execute();
$katarray=$stmtkat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
var_dump($katarray);
```

The return array i get:

```
 array(2) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["kategorie"]=> string(12) "Coaching" }
```

The table has 4 rows, why do i get only the first row into the array?
What i am doing wrong? Obviously i am new to PDO.

Ty for your time.

Comment: That gives me the data output: Array ( [id] => 1 [kategorie] => Coaching )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are only fetching one of the result rows produced by your query

If you use `->fetch()` to get result rows one at a time you do it in a while loop like this

```
$stmtkat = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM kategorie");
$stmtkat->execute();
while ( $katarray=$stmtkat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    var_dump($katarray);
}
```

Or use `fetchAll()` to return all rows into a local array from a single call to the PDO Stmt object

```
$stmtkat = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM kategorie");
$stmtkat->execute();
$katarray=$stmtkat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {

var_dump($katarray);
```

Comment: was just about to comment you could mention fetchAll as well, +1 :)

Comment: @JimL Yup that occured to me only when I realised he had called the variable `$katarray`. Thanks for the nudge

Comment: Thanks, that did it :)

Answer (score 2):

You get only one row in return because:

> PDOStatement::fetch — Fetches the next row from a result set

Use `fetchAll()` instead to get full `array()` of result or use `fetch()` inside `while()` loop.

Example with `fetch()` and `while()`:

```
while ($stmtkat->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  var_dump($katarray);
}
```

Example with `fetchAll()`:

```
$result = $stmtkat->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
var_dup($result);
```

Comment: Thank you too, that was it.